# React 共通処理でstateを変えたい

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

on/offを切り替えるswitchがあり、切り替えるときにchangeState関数が呼ばれます。
引数として渡されるkeyの中身は{numberState: true}の形で渡されます。
渡された値でstateを変えたいのですがうまくいきません
わかる人がいましたら教えて欲しいです。よろしくお願いします。

コンポーネントはmaterialUIを使っています

```
interface IState {
  numbers: boolean;
  symbol: boolean;
  texxt: boolean;
}

const index:FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IState>();

 const changeState = (key: IState) => {
    console.log(key)
    // setStateでうまくstateを変更できない
    setState({ ...state, ...{ key: !key }});
  };

 <Switch
  checked={numberState}
  onChange={(e) => changeState({ numberState: e.target.checked })}
 />
 <Switch
  checked={textState}
  onChange={(e) => changeState({ textState: e.target.checked })}
 />
 <Switch
  checked={symbolState}
  onChange={(e) => changeState({ symbolState: e.target.checked })}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

`onChange`で取得した値は既に反映後の状態なので、`boolean`値を反転させる必要は無いかと思います。

```js
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
import { Switch } from "@material-ui/core";

interface IState {
  numberState: boolean;
  symbolState: boolean;
  textState: boolean;
}

const initIState = {
  numberState: false,
  symbolState: false,
  textState: false,
};

const Index: FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<IState>(initIState);

  const changeState = (key: Partial<IState>) => {
    console.log(key);
    setState({ ...state, ...key });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Switch
        checked={state.numberState}
        onChange={(e) => changeState({ numberState: e.target.checked })}
      />
      <Switch
        checked={state.textState}
        onChange={(e) => changeState({ textState: e.target.checked })}
      />
      <Switch
        checked={state.symbolState}
        onChange={(e) => changeState({ symbolState: e.target.checked })}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default Index;
```